# no features in bash in new vps?

Tags: server, bash

I have 12.04 server minimal running on my VPS. When I ssh into the server, only `$` is showing at the prompt for each prompt. There's no typical `<directory> <username>$`, no autocompletion (bash-completion is installed), and no use of arrow key, etc. I'm suspecting `bash` or `.bashrc` is not sourced or something?

How do I get the standard bash features working?

edit: `bash`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile` exist in the filesystem.

Here is my `ps` output:

```
$ ps 
PID  TTY   TIME    CMD 
4053 pts/0 00:00:00 sh 
4055 pts/0 00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: If you run `ps`, are you being shown `sh` or `bash`? Your logon shell could be `sh`.

Comment: $ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4053 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
 4055 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ you're right! I changed default shell to bash with `chsh`.

Comment: So my answer below helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you aren't even using Bash. Your `ps` output shows why:

```
$ ps 
PID  TTY   TIME    CMD 
4053 pts/0 00:00:00 sh 
4055 pts/0 00:00:00 ps
```

Try running `bash`:

```
$ bash
```

and you should get this prompt:

```
something@somewhere ~:$
```

Now change it to be the default:

```
chsh /bin/bash
```

If the command is not found, you need to install `bash`:

```
sudo apt-get install bash
```

or use whatever steps are appropriate on your VPS to install packages(most likely this).