# How to make the apt autocompletion work in minimal system (in LXC container)?

Tags: 12.04, bash, lxc

When I work inside thin LXC container on 12.04 I have only very basic system. In particular the `/etc/bash_completion.d` is missing the e.g. `apt`, that I find particularly useful.

Is there any standard package, that installs the autocompletion for the apt, or should I copy the file manually? And just copying the files into /etc/bash_completion.d manually just doesn't seem to work.

I use `bash` as my command interpreter.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.

There are 4 essential things required for auto completion:

1. Bash
2. Executable script `/etc/bash_completion` (this is the part I was missing)
3. Not-executable scripts in folder `/etc/bash_completion.d`. I believe they get installed silently together with the associated packages.
4. Execution of the script `/etc/bash_completion` within the Bash (the standard `~/.bashrc` takes care of that)

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the right answer.

Comment: @OrangeTux I will... But "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" - says AskUbuntu.com

Comment: Of course, I forgot that.

Comment: The script /etc/bash_completion comes with the package bash-completion: apt-get install bash-completion

Answer (score 3):

Are you even runnning Bash?

Try `bash`. Does `something@somewhere ~:$` appear and is autocompletion reanebled? 
If so set default bash by `chsh /bin/bash`.

More information in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204589/no-features-in-bash-in-new-vps).

Comment: Yes I run bash, but it is a good remark.

Comment: I believe you forgot the command argument. Should be: `chsh -s /bin/bash`. Otherwise chsh tries to find user `/bin/bash`...